# Problems exporting Jar using Weka

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath, weka

i've got a big problem exporting my project as a jar file (inside my project i use weka). I'm using Eclipse.
I've added in **Java Build Path** *weka.jar* and i've attached to it *weka-src.jar*, testing my classifier under eclipse everything works, so i've decided to create a jar (because i need that another program use it).
First of all i've created the manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ weka.jar weka-src.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: start.Home
Main-Class: start.Home
```

The main class of the program is Home (inside the package start), while weka.jar and weka-src.jar are inside the /src/ directory of the eclipse program.
When i try to execute the jar created i receive this output:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/classifiers/Classifier
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.classifiers.Classifier
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

I think that the problem is the CLASSPATH so i've tried to solve it in this way:
I've created the Environment Variable CLASSPATH with this values:

```
C:\Users\tomma\Desktop\workspace Eclipse\AndroidPermissionsClassifier\src\weka.jar
C:\Users\tomma\Desktop\workspace Eclipse\AndroidPermissionsClassifier\src\weka-src.jar
```

but nothing changed, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You are right: the classpath is the problem. Did you remove the items from the manifest classpath when you added them to the environment CLASSPATH? (Side note: place the source jar in the -sourcepath, not the classpath.)